# Is there a way to select/deselect multiple files/directories in Vifm?

Tags: vifm

I could not find a command which lets me to select/deselect multiple files/directories in [Vifm](http://vifm.sourceforge.net). Is there one in Vifm that operates something like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>in [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org)?

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>t</kbd> is the default map for select/deselect multiple files. Sorry, I mapped the key in `vifmrc` for another function.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter to visual mode with `v` then `j` or `k` to select/deselect desirable files. Also can yank multiple files with `Ny` where N is a number like 5 or 10.

Other interesting thing is select files by a regex: `/pattern` and them `t` to select, `n` to go to next occurrence, `t` to select it, and so on...

I don't know if there is a way to select multiple file with command `t` as a single command like `Nt`.